# php proto-buffer

Tags: php

Использую библиотеку: https://github.com/allegro/php-protobuf
Версия php 7.0
Инсталяция была произведена по документации либы.
При компиляции foo.proto (php protoc-gen-php.php foo.proto) получаю следующую ошибку в консоли: ERROR: protobuf module is not installed
На VPS установлен phpize и protobuf 3.6.1.
Возможно кто-то имел идентичную проблему и может помочь в ее ришении.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в инстале protobuf